# Slow Insert into Azure SQL database from python list of rows

Tags: azure

Hi everyone I am struggling with this problem: I am trying to insert in an azure db a python list made of approx 100k rows, using this code:

```
list_of_rows = [...]
self.azure_cursor.fast_executemany = True
self.azure_cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''',list_of_rows)
```

The problem is that it takes ages to do that (about 43 seconds for 100k rows, for an amount of less than 30 MB of data) and I don't know how to improve it, because I am already using fast_executemany and as seen from azure dashboard I don't reach max DTU granted by my subscription plan (S1-20 DTU).
I've also tried to see if an index would help, but there are no advantages (and trying to run the query in SSMS no index is recommended).
Finally, the problem is not about connection, since I am using 1Gb/s download/upload

Does someone know how to improve these performances?

**UPDATE**

Tried to use the code below as suggested in the page linked by by Shiraz Bhaiji:

Firstly, I create a pandas dataframe from my list of rows, then set up the engine and create the event listener and then I use df.to_sql

```
self.df = pd.DataFrame(data = list_of_rows , columns=['A','B','C'])
params='DRIVER=driver;SERVER=server;PORT=1433;DATABASE=databas;UID=username;PWD=password'
db_params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(db_params))

@event.listens_for(self.engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
          cursor.fast_executemany = True
df.to_sql('table_name', self.engine, index=False, if_exists="append", schema="dbo")
```

The code below takes the same time as pure executemany. I tried to remove PK (there are no other indexes on the table) and it made insert faster, now it takes 22 seconds, but is too much for 100k rows for a total amount of 30 MB of data

Comment: Are you running this locally against an Azure SQL database, or is this code executed within Azure? If executing in Azure, are you in the same region as your database?

Comment: I am executing this code on my computer, connecting to Azure db which is located in northern switzerland and I am in Italy. Switzerland was the best option based on distance

Comment: Are you eventually going to move your Python code to execute in the same Azure region, or are you just hosting your data there? I ask, because running within the same region will likely give you a pretty big boost. Then you will get a real picture of how fast it will execute.

Comment: There is a chance I will deploy my code into Azure, but right now I have to send data from my computer, since I am getting and manipulating them from my machine

Answer (score 0):

If you use the to_sql function instead, you can speed up the inserts.

See: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/speed-up-bulk-inserts-to-sql-db-using-pandas-and-python-61707ae41990

Comment: Unfortunatly, this didn't work for me. I tried but the time to insert my set of rows is the same as inserting them using executemany

Comment: I updated the question with the code I've used as seen in the linked page. Am I making some mistakes?